# 3D Transform (rotateY) in Chrome and Firefox do react differently

Tags: css, css-transforms

I created a CSS 3D Transformation for a logo div within a header of my page. On hover the logo gets rotated. Everything looks fine in Chrome, but Firefox renders it completely different.

I moved the transform origin to the left side of the logo div. When rotating the right side of the div gets "compressed" to get the visual 3D effect. In Firefox the logo div only gets smaller but not "compressed" and you can't see a 3D effect.

The Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        #header {
            width: 940px;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: blue;
            height: 350px;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-perspective: 800;
            -moz-perspective: 800;
        }

        #logo {
            width: 300px;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: red;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 0px;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
            -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
            -moz-transition-duration: 0.25s;
            -moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
            -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -moz-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);

        }
        #logo:hover {
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
            -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,45deg);
            -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
            -moz-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,45deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please try the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4CN5g/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong besides using CSS3 3D transformations and expecting consistent results across browsers. Firefox doesn't distort the image to give the illusion of depth the way that Chrome does.

Comment: just add 'px' to this (-moz-perspective: 800px;) line of css code

Answer (score 0):

As @Uttara commented:

In the CSS rule for `#header`

Change

```
-moz-perspective: 800;
```

to

```
-moz-perspective: 800px;
```

then Firefox will give same effect as Chrome