# How to make a div flip consistently across browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, flip

I am trying to make a div flip in the horizontal plane using css and JQuery. I found some code on JSFiddle that does this very neatly, but I can't understand why it does not work on Firefox, but works on Chrome and Safari (I've only tested it on OSX at the moment).

http://jsfiddle.net/TLCqu/2/

The css is as follows:

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
}
.flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
.flip .card .front {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flip .card .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    background: blue;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I added `-moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);` after `-webkit-transform:` anywhere this was used. This has the strange effect of making the text reverse, but not the div. I'm not sure what works in webkit or what I should be changing.

Comment: This might have someting to do with the `-webkit` prefix.. Maybe this can help you in some direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400436/3d-transform-rotatey-in-chrome-and-firefox-do-react-differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mozilla, you need to use `-moz-`. Here is an updated version of your CSS:

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
}
.flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    -moz-perspective: 800;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
.flip .card .front {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flip .card .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    background: blue;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/TLCqu/3/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work on Firefox, because `-webkit` is only for webkit browsers. Firefox uses gecko, you'll want to add -mozilla prefixes for mozilla support.

Check out [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) for a list of browser support for the features you're using. A lot of the CSS 3d transforms are still pretty experimental.